# Object keys iteration issue

Tags: javascript

I've got this API call to marvel and I am exporting it and saving as a state in React.

```
 avengers.map((avenger, index) => {
  const url = `
    http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/${avenger}?ts=${ts}&apikey=${publicKey}&hash=${hash}
  `
  fetchMarvelData(url, index)
})

let fetchedData = {}

async function fetchMarvelData (url, index) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  const data = await response.json()
  fetchedData[`avenger${index}`] = data.data.results[0]
}

export default fetchedData
```

When I try to iterate Object.keys(fetchedData) I get an empty array. Not quite sure what is wrong here, any help is appreciated.

[React state log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgZEo.png)

EDIT: Clarified what I am trying to iterate over.

EDIT: Added image of React state console.log

Comment: When you try to iterate what? Please post what you tried

Comment: *"When I try to iterate with Object.keys() I get an empty array."*. Of course, because you are doing `Object.keys({})`.

Comment: where is the console log?

Comment: `Object.keys(avenger0)`? Tried putting the object into that `.keys` method?

Comment: You're probably getting the keys of an empty object.

Comment: where are you printing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're exporting an empty object. Since you're doing asynchronous calls that you aren't `await`ing, fetchedData will just be an empty object at the time of export.

If you want all the requests to finish before, you could do something like this:

```js
const hash         = '...'; // Replace
const ts           = '...'; // Replace
const publicKey    = '...'; // Replace
const fetchOptions = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
};

const fetchAvenger = async avenger => {
  const url      = `http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/${avenger}?ts=${ts}&apikey=${publicKey}&hash=${hash}`;
  const response = await fetch(url, fetchOptions);
  const data     = await response.json();

  return data.data.results[0];
};

const fetchAvengers = async avengers => {
  const remoteAvengers = [];
  await Promise.all(avengers.map(async avenger => {
    const remoteAvenger = await fetchAvenger(avenger);
    remoteAvengers.push(remoteAvenger);
  }));
  return remoteAvengers;
};

export default fetchAvengers;
```

And then in your component you could add the the avengers to state like so:

```
import fetchAvengers from 'path/to/fetchAvengers';
// ...

// Show a loader or something?
this.setState({ isFetchingAvengers: true });

// Waits for all avengers to be fetched from api
const avengers = await fetchAvengers([...]);

// Update state, hide loader
this.setState({ avengers, isFetchingAvengers: false });
```

I haven't tested the code so there might be some errors in it, let me know and I'll try to help.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused because console would log state data (see image) so it looked like async call worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

According to your console out put given above.
There is an empty object at top with no props in it.